# VBA: Refresh Cells to Update Chart Axes

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to write code that will auto-update chart axes on several charts. Cell AM5 contains `=D7` and I think the issue is although AM5 is updating to the correct value, the chart axes are not updating.

If I select AM5, press F2 and Enter without modifying, the chart axes update therefore I must have to refresh the cell AM5, even though the value updates.

I'm looking for code to be applied before the code below to refresh columns AM & AN, i.e. simulating pressing F2 + Enter, for all cells.

Code to auto-update chart axes is below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Location1 plots
  With Worksheets("Location1_Plots").ChartObjects("ABC48hr").Chart
    Select Case Target.Address
      Case "$AM$6"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$AM$5"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$AN$6"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$AN$5"
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Target.Value
    End Select
  End With
  With Worksheets("Location_Plots").ChartObjects("ABC5Day").Chart
    Select Case Target.Address
      Case "$AM$12"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$AM$11"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$AN$12"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$AN$11"
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Target.Value
    End Select
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so what is the question ? are you getting an error ?

Comment: No error, but when I change the start date if the time series in D7, the chart axes do not update. However, when I manually refresh AM5 - which only contains =D7 - by pressing F2 & Enter, the chart axes do update. So I need a bit of code to sit above the code I have already to simulate this F2 & Enter process; I could record a macro but I'm assuming there is a process to refresh or recalculate the cells in VBA so the chart axes will update.

Comment: Have you set  .ScreenUpdating = False, in other part of the code. If yes, you may require to set it True.

Comment: Application.ScreenUpdating was not defined. I added this in at the beginning of the Sub but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.CalculateFullRebuild` may help you. Refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822609.aspx). Place it before you exit the method.